# command line could not overridden cucumber options

Tags: java, selenium, maven, cucumber

**my pom.xml is below and the automation is working fine. but when the automation is run using command line, always use runner configuration and does not override the runner file.
I used command**

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/features/myfeature.feature", it always run all test scenario instead of containing scenarios in myfeature file
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `cucumber.options` property has been removed. To select a single feature file you can use `cucumber.features`.

For other properties see:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/core#properties-environment-variables-system-options

Comment: The link you provided doesn't work, it gives me a 404. I'm trying to set the `pretty` option, but am not having any luck.

Answer (score 0):

pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>OpenText</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TestApp</name>
    <description>TestApp Web Automation</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <selenium.version>4.1.1</selenium.version>
        <junit.version>4.13.2</junit.version>
        <cucumber.version>7.3.4</cucumber.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version>
        <webdriver.manager.version>5.0.2</webdriver.manager.version>
        <ng.webdriver.version>1.1.6</ng.webdriver.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>${webdriver.manager.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paulhammant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ngwebdriver</artifactId>
            <version>${ng.webdriver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```